# ORDER BY CASE WHEN: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list

Tags: sql-order-by, union, case-when

I have this example code of something I'm trying to run. Only he table names and column names were changed. What I want to do is have a result set of states and have 'NULL' be the first value and the rest of the results appear below 'NULL' in ascending order and I can't for the life of me make it work. I get the error at the bottom. This may be a very "noobish" question, but can anyone help? Much appreciated everyone!

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
    State
FROM    TABLE1 (NOLOCK)
WHERE   COLUMN1 NOT LIKE '%THAT%'
    AND COLUMN1 NOT LIKE '%THIS%'
UNION
SELECT  'NULL'
ORDER BY ( CASE WHEN State = 'NULL' THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END );
```

Error Message:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
```

Comment: you should inform/tag the rdbms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select that column... even if you don't use it later, the order by requires it to be present in the select.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
    State,
 CASE WHEN State = 'NULL' THEN 0
            ELSE 1 END orderId
FROM    TABLE1 (NOLOCK)
WHERE   COLUMN1 NOT LIKE '%THAT%'
    AND COLUMN1 NOT LIKE '%THIS%'
ORDER BY ( CASE WHEN State = 'NULL' THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END );
```

Comment: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: I need to update my answer, why do you need the union null in your query?

Comment: I removed the union... just let me know if that returns the data as you expect it